# Android Studio can't create new activity

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

The finish button is trapped of-screen, and I can't rezise the window...

Any advice appreciated

Comment: ... hide your toolbar.

Comment: Can you shrink the size of the window then drag up?

Comment: Use Tab on your keyboard to select the Finish and click Enter.

Comment: I would rather avoid having hide the toolbar be the solution here, since I USE said toolbar.

The window can't be resized.

I can try and use tab, but this rather bothers me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bring your cursor down to Windows task bar, Android studio will automatically scroll up this window. Hence button will be visible and accessible.

Comment: @user633314 Go to View. Enter full screen.

Comment: That does work. Do you know of a way without using that? I hate to be petty, but if there is a way without the toolbar missing..?

Comment: @user633314  After setting up everything just press enter. As Finish button is selected by default, it will be pressed by clicking enter

Comment: Good enough, you have it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment you can use Tab. I had the same issue a while ago, due to a screen issue.